# How do I make my header smaller and push up my branding and nav?

Tags: html, css, header, landscape

[image: index.html]

I'm trying to make the header smaller in landscape mode & push up the Branding & Nav.

I haven't been able to make the header smaller after already trying simple things like "height:" etc. and also when I try to push up the branding & nav, the nav goes up but not the branding. Here's the HTML and CSS that I'm using.

Can someone please help?
Also I'm currently learning by following tutorials on YouTube... does anyone have any suggested reading materials or cheatsheets for beginners who are getting started?

```css
/* Landscape */

@media (max-height:500px) {
  header {
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  header #branding,
  header nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>
        <span class="highlight">Acme</span> Web Design
      </h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `@media (max-height:500px)` is a really abd way in checking for landscape. This will be only true on smartphones. A smarter media query would be: `@media only screen and (orientation: landscape)`. Last but not least, the `top` property only takes effect in combination with a `position` property sauch as `sticky`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: Please be more clear and specfic. What do you mean with `push up` and `make my header smaller`? Push the Logo and Branding above the other element flow-wise or layer-wise? smaller: vertically or horizontally? by how much smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you transform your container to a flexbox, then align it vertically:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

For making the header smaller, you should provide complete CSS so I can see what is going on. But for short, you may reduce your line height:

```css
header #branding {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```